# UTF8 safe preg_quote() alternative?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

There doesn't seem to be an mb version of this function, as far as I can tell from the PHP docs on it ([found here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)). Someone apparently already brought this up, but their report was brushed aside because it wasn't formatted properly ([found here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36444)). Is there an alternative for preg_quote() that I'm unaware of, or is it just going to have to be a large regex for UTF8 strings?

If it makes a difference (and I doubt it does, but I might as well throw it out there), the characters I need to process are Chinese Simplified, which is a subset of the Japanese character set (Katakana).

To be clear, I did attempt to just use preg_quote(), but it mangled the characters.

Comment: Don't use mb_* library for regular expressions, because PCRE supports UTF8 with *u* modifier.

Comment: 1) Japanese is not "Katakana" and simplified Chinese is not really a subset of it. 2) What problems exactly are you encountering? Show a piece of sample code (the closed bug report didn't have any sample either). 3) Works for me: http://3v4l.org/Rn0eT

Answer (score 6):

I too was looking at this but then looked at utf-8 encoding and realized it will not have an issue because all the bytes in a multi-byte sequence have their msb set to 1 and all the preg_quote affected characters are in the ASCII 7-bit range. There is no overlap in the affected characters so preg_quote will work fine.

You will have an issue if you use a multi-byte delimiter but I don't know why you would want that or if it is supported.

Although the question is a year old, I thought it would help others looking for the same information.